# Hadoop - how to use and reduce multiple inputs?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
Mapper/Reducer 1 --> (key,value)
                      /   |   \
                     /    |    \
     Mapper/Reducer 2     |    Mapper/Reducer 4
     -> (oKey,oValue)     |    -> (xKey, xValue)
                          |
                          |
                    Mapper/Reducer 3
                    -> (aKey, aValue)
```

I have a logfile, which i aggregate with MR1. The Mapper2, Mapper3, Mapper4 takes the output of MR1 as their input. Jobs are chained.

MR1 Output:

```
User     {infos of user:[{data here},{more data},{etc}]}
..
```

MR2 Output:

```
timestamp       idCount
..
```

MR3 Output:

```
timestamp        loginCount
..
```

MR4 Output:

```
timestamp        someCount
..
```

I want to combine the outputs from MR2-4 : Final output->

```
timestamp     idCount     loginCount   someCount
..
..
..
```

Is there a way w/o Pig or Hive? I'm using Java.

Comment: +1 for the ASCII art alone..

Comment: Is it not possible to have a multi-functional MR job for the second step, seeing as your keys are all timestamps? I.e. interpret the value that has been passed in and handle it accordingly? Seeing as reducers are guaranteed to receive all values for a given key, you can gather up all info related to a timestamp and write it out only when you have all the components you need.

Comment: Actually i did this and it worked. One question popped up: To achieve what i wanted i wrote 3 times in the map-function to the context (context.write(key1,value1) -- deeper in code context.write(key2,value2) and in the end context.write(key3,value3). Is this viable?

Comment: Technically yes, but then you'll have 3 separate lines, albeit in the same file next to each other. I was thinking you could store the key-value pairs as they come in to the reducer in say a multimap, and then when you've "collected" all components for that key in the map, write it out in a single context.write()

Comment: +1 hats off for your indentation skills

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) see sample [here](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't have array of output in reducer class.
What comes to my mind to solve your problem is the following:

Your **output key for MR1** would be one of `{a,b,c}` and **value** is pair among `{timestamp,idCount}` or `{timestamp, loginCount}` or `{timestamp, someCount}` according to keys. And you will combine **MR2-4**.

So the process is going to be like that:

```
MR1 <inputKey,inputValue,outputKey,outPutValue> where outputKey is 
                                       "a" for outValue`{timestamp,idCount}
                                       "b" for outValue`{timestamp, loginCount} 
                                       "c" for outValue`{timestamp, someCount} 

MR2-4<inputKey,inputValue,outputKey,outPutValue> if inputkey is "a" do MR2
                                                 if inputkey is "b" do MR3
                                                 if inputkey is "c" do MR4
```

Also, there are methods called `Partitioner and GroupComperator` in which you can play with {key/value} and mapper/reducer can consider `key+some_part_of_value` as key.